# Finding the children of a git commit, not on the current branch, or any branch at all

Tags: git

Is it possible for me to find the children of a commit? All commands I've found, in either the man pages or suggestions from other people usually involve the branch name.

What I've effectively done is this:
I have a commit tree:

```
A-B-C-D
      ^
```

My branch is pointing to D.

I've then rolled back to C, and committed E:

```
A-B-C-D
     \
      E
      ^
```

However in `git rev-list`, or in visual tools such as Sourcetree, it is, not surprisingly, displayed as

```
A-B-C-E
      ^
```

With no reference to D.

Obviously the commit D is stil in my repo, but without the commit ID, I'm having trouble locating it. Is there a command for displaying the children of a commit, regardless of what branch they're on, or if they're on a branch at all?

**Edit**

From the Nevik's answer below, `--all` doesn't seem to show the unreferenced commit. Taking this commit structure:

```
> git log --graph --oneline
* 0ff0f06 d
* ac06e14 c
* 3c45cce b
* b3aa730 a
```

And then rolling back to c:

```
> git reset --soft ac06
> git log --graph --oneline --all
* ac06e14 c
* 3c45cce b
* b3aa730 a
```

And then resetting back to d:

```
> git reset --soft 0ff0
> git log --graph --oneline --all
* 0ff0f06 d
* ac06e14 c
* 3c45cce b
* b3aa730 a
```

So the commit is definitely still in the repo.

Comment: Note that if a commit is not reachable from any branch or tag it will eventually be garbage collected, so commit D is not "obviously" still in the repo.

Comment: Ah yes, but if a gc hasn't happened then commit is still there? I should still be able to reference the commit. If I knew its ID.

Comment: @NoelM: If gc didn't happen you can try to use reflog, either for a specific branch, or a reflog for HEAD.  Note that reflog entries are kept only for limited time, by default 30 days for commits unreachable otherwise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `git reflog` / `git log -g` (`git log --walk-reflogs`) or `git reflog <branch>`.

---

### An example:

Let's start with the following situation

```
> git log --graph --oneline
* 84be53e d
* 8932c9a c
* 05cbe59 b
* 469baa5 a
```

"Remove" top commit.  It is quite similar to doing `git commit --amend` to correct a top (latest) commit:

```
> git reset --soft HEAD~1
```

<sub>*Note: this is equivalent to `git reset --soft 8932c`*</sub>

As you wrote `--all` doesn't help in this situation, as 84be53e becomes unreachable.

```
> git log --graph --oneline --all
* 8932c9a c
* 05cbe59 b
* 469baa5 a
```

[`git reflog`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reflog.html) to the rescue... :-)

```
> git reflog
8932c9a HEAD@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
84be53e HEAD@{1}: commit: d
8932c9a HEAD@{2}: commit: c
05cbe59 HEAD@{3}: commit: b
469baa5 HEAD@{4}: commit (initial): a
```

If you are switching between branches then the branch specific reflog might be better:

```
> git branch
* master
> git reflog master
8932c9a master@{0}: reset: moving to HEAD~1
84be53e master@{1}: commit: d
8932c9a master@{2}: commit: c
05cbe59 master@{3}: commit: b
469baa5 master@{4}: commit (initial): a
```

<sub>*Note: if you were using git-aware shell prompt showing current branch then using `git branch` to check current branch would be not necessary.*</sub>

Now you can use `git reset --soft 84be5` or `git reset --soft HEAD@{1}` or `git reset --soft master@{1}` (or use shorter form for latest: `git reset --soft @{1}`).

```
> git reset --soft @{1}
> git log --graph --oneline --all
* 84be53e d
* 8932c9a c
* 05cbe59 b
* 469baa5 a
```

**See also:** [reflog, your safety net](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/02/09/reflog-your-safety-net.html) on [gitready](http://gitready.com) (for example).

Comment: Yep, reflog sorted it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `--all` switch for [`git log`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) and [`git rev-list`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) to display commits from all branches (and even those which arent on branches).

Comment: This doesn't do it. I've updated my question referencing `--all`